# Can files be copied from an Ubuntu VM to a Windows host without SSH?

Tags: virtualbox

Can files be copied from an Ubuntu VM to a Windows host **without** SSH?

I ask this since coping files via SSH requires me to install an S**SH server** on *Windows* (either on Windows itself or on *WSL*) and I would rather pass on that as I don't have any other reason to do so.

This should use me to backup my files.

What I do now to backup files to WSL:

```
(
sudo mysqldump -u root --password --all-databases > /var/www/html/db.sql
sudo zip -r /var/www/html/dr.zip /var/www/html
sudo scp /var/www/html/db.sql /var/www/html/dr.zip USER@IP:/mnt/c/Users/USER/Desktop/
sudo rm /var/www/html/db.sql /var/www/html/dr.zip
)
```

As you can see I use the above code block to copy files from my Ubuntu to Windows via SSH.

I aspire to run a similar command set in Ubuntu to copy my files to the host machine (Windows) but this time without SSH and with some local way.

Comment: Yes, with samba for example, if it´s a server then you don't even need the vboxlinuxadditions. Is this an option for you or you want something else

Comment: That is the fastest way....you just need to `sudo apt install samba` and share the folder.

Comment: Is it good for GUI as well?

Comment: If you share the folder you can access it on your network with any machine...and you can set it with password or without it. How do you mean 'good for GUI'... That virtualbox will be visible on the network and when you open it there will be your shared folder like from any other windows machine. The only question is do you want that or something else?

Comment: You don't need an SSH server to copy files to, or from a ubuntu VM. All you need is a suitable SFTP client

Comment: Why bidirectional drag and drop or Shared Folders features don't work for you?

Comment: I would prefer a way that doesn't include either sftp or ssh. Something local, that would allow doing so easily from both GUI and CLI.

Comment: True, that was my second solution. It depends if you want to access that shared folder very often or just now...if you want to have a permanent shared folder without ssh then samba is the best solution. If it's very rare that you will need access to that folder then use SFTP

Comment: @Benia if you want me to, I can answer it for you and explain how easy is to setup a shared folder with samba

Comment: I believe Samba is what I need, though i'll try to update my question to better describe.

Comment: I've just edited the question @lewis4u.

Comment: I see, you can also make a shared folder on your host machine and share it to guest and you can save your backups to that folder and access it. maybe that would be also an option? But for this you must install the vboxlinuxadditions

Comment: That sounds good, very good even. I could save the backups (automatically made inside Linux) into this folder.

Comment: Yes...did you install the vboxlinuxadditions?

Comment: No for now I don't use a dedicated server and hence don't use VB (though I used in the past). For now I only use WSL. If you publish an answer, just choose the tool that seems best fit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57248/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-benia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to install the samba and share a folder from your server.

1. Install samba

   ```
   sudo apt install samba
   ```
2. Add your linux user to samba:

   ```
   sudo smbpasswd -a <username>
   // then it will ask you to write the password
   // for that user and to confirm it
   ```
3. In this file `/etc/samba/smb.conf` just write to the bottom at the end:

   ```
   [shared_folder_name]

   comment = some_comment
   path = /path/to/your/folder
   browsable = yes
   valid users = your_username
   read only = no
   ```

After this you can see that folder on the network and access it like every other shared folder.

p.s. i think you must restart the samba service or just reboot the VM!

Comment: Oh and Lewis, can you please give a few more words about securing this dir? I would assume that giving it the same password of the sudoer would be enough and that no further actions are needed (I thought about the issue of brute forcing its password but it doesn't seem likely to me that it can be done without the hacker hacking either of the 2 systems first).

Comment: Well I think you are pretty safe with if you set a different password for samba and make it a long one (more than 20 char long) and brute force will take very long to crack it. With technology of today 50years+

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox/virtualbox should do it. You can mount your Dropbox through your VM. Unless I am misunderstanding what you need.